# Solution to avoid duplicate css IDs on the same page

Tags: html, css, w3c-validation

I am creating a presentation page that shows some possible cms system messages on the same page (errors, notices, etc.). I have created a php function to output the whole div of a system message exactly in the same way the cms does, so this way the html output is using the same css styles of the current styling template and as a result I can have say 5 different messages on the same page, one below the other.

The problem is that when these are generated by the php function, all div IDs get repeated and when I try to validate the page I of course get:

**Duplicate ID system-message.**

One solution is to go on every line of the css and add a custom class as well and then use that class instead of the original IDs. Something like:

```
#system-message,
.system-message-custom
{….}

#system-message ul,
.system-message-custom ul
{….}

#system-message div div p,
.system-message-custom div div p
{….}
```

..but I don't find this very smart because if I change the cms template to one that has no custom classes added then the whole thing will not work.

This question might be funny but, is there any way to like, copy `#system-message` to `.system-message-custom` and finish with it ? I've seen some sass examples but I am not sure if it can be done, I have never tried sass yet actually.

What would you do ? just ignore the validation maybe ? The idea of using javascript for this would not make me so happy. I hope I was understood and have not confused you. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If it is merely for presentation and not going to be the functionality of the  CMS system to show more than one system message at a time, then I would put validation on the side for now.

Comment: you already know the solution. You stated that the php function generates all divs with repeated id names. So, go in the php function and change how the id's are named.

Comment: @ChrisB thanks for your help, yes it is for presentation of template styles, on the web though. The script is indeed only used for that, but I hate seeing the validation dropping 11 errors and 22 warnings just because of this. I am also not sure if that can affect SEO.

Comment: @SvenBieder thanks too brother, I can edit the function yes, but have to edit each template css and add all those lines too <- this is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @durduvakis when the cms-system you use is badly planned from the beginning then it comes to more work in the end. That's the fact for every project. When you want to make a real future use out of it, after the presentation then you better make some quality code instead of a quick and dirty workaround.

Comment: @SvenBieder I agree with you, If I was to redesign those divs I would never use IDs, but I am not the one that added those IDs in Joomla 2.5 :)